# MyBatis - Nested Conditions in Where Clause

Tags: ibatis, mybatis

I'm dynamically generating the where clause inside MyBatis v3 mapper xml. However placing parentheses is really cumbersome. Is there an easier way to handle the problem without using if statements?

```html
<where>
  <if test="filter != null">
    <choose>
      <when test="filter.lref != null">
        file.lref = #{filter.lref}
      </when>
      <otherwise>
        <!-- I don't want to use this -->
        <if test="filter.forLike != null || filter.forInt != null">
          ( 
        </if>
        <if test="filter.forLike != null" >
          subject LIKE #{filter.forLike}    
          OR requester_identifier LIKE #{filter.forLike}
          OR requester_name LIKE #{filter.forLike}
        </if>
        <if test="filter.forInt != null">
          OR file_id = #{filter.forInt}
        </if>

        <!-- I don't want to use this -->
        <if test="filter.forLike != null || filter.forInt != null">
          ) 
        </if>
      </otherwise>
    </choose>
  </if>
  <if test="listMode > 0">
    <choose>
       <when test="listMode == 1">
         AND file_status_link.dosya_ref is not NULL
       </when>
       <otherwise>
         AND file_status_link.dosya_ref is NULL
       </otherwise>
    </choose>
   </if>            
</where>
```

Sample dynamically generated SQL output is as follows

```
WHERE ( subject LIKE ? OR requester_identifier LIKE ? OR requester_name LIKE ? ) 
AND file_status_link.dosya_ref is NULL
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to encapsulate that part inside `<trim>` tag. It would be something like this:

```xml
<trim prefix="(" prefixOverrides="OR" suffix=")">
  <if test="filter.forLike != null" >
    subject LIKE #{filter.forLike}    
    OR requester_identifier LIKE #{filter.forLike}
    OR requester_name LIKE #{filter.forLike}
  </if>
  <if test="filter.forInt != null">
    OR file_id = #{filter.forInt}
  </if>
</trim>
```

Comment: You are right @partlov. But it did not solve the problem :( When `filter.forLike` is null then `OR` is not cleared out. Your suggestion is necessary to handle this situation. If both `filter.forLike` and `filter.forInt` is null and if we remove the **unwanted** if clauses then the SQL output is: `WHERE ( ) AND file_status_link.dosya_ref is NULL` Anyway, trim is still the closest option to solve the problem.

Comment: According to your edit we didn't understand each other. Remove your two `if` causes. Trim will automatically add `(` and `)` if needed. Also id `OR` is first word inside `<trim>` it should be replaced with `(` - that is done by `prefixOverrides`.

Comment: Now I totally understood and applied your solution, thank you for the clarification. Trim does two jobs at the same time: 1. Cleans up prefixes-suffixes if underlying string is empty. 2. Removes overriden keywords if underlying string starts with them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-SQL (XML-SQL):

```
where
    1 = 1
    <A>and file.lref = #{filter.lref}</A>
    <D>and (
        <E>
        subject like #{filter.forLike}    
        or requester_identifier like #{filter.forLike}
        or requester_name like #{filter.forLike}
        </E>
        <F>or file_id = #{filter.forInt}</F>
    )</D>
    </B>
    <C>and file_status_link.dosya_ref is <G>not</G> null</C>
```

Where:

```
A: <B> && filter.lref != null
B: filter != null
D: <B> && (<E> || <F>)
E: filter.forLike != null
F: filter.forInt != null
C: listMode > 0
G: listMode == 1
```