# How to Do a Complex If Conditioning in MyBatis

Tags: java, sql, mybatis, ibatis

I want to test the following condition in the `if` clause of the MyBatis:

```
(x = null or x = '') and y != null and y != ''
```

However, when I place it in `<if test=...`, the content of `if` doesn't get added to the dynamically generated SQL, even though `x` is indeed null and `y` has a value. How should a condition like this be handled in MyBatis?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306949/mybatis-nested-conditions-in-where-clause?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning x variable, not comparing. Change

```
(x = null or x = '') and y != null and y != ''
```

by

```
(x == null or x == '') and y != null and y != ''
```

Comment: Or use `<choose><when>` to select only one outcome and not the other. Thanks for catching the obvious.